# How do I bake 'Sugar Cookies' but my oven does not go high enough?

Tags: cookies

I am trying to bake sugar cookies but the recipe I am using says to bake at 350 for 5-7 minutes. My oven only goes to 200.
Could someone help me and tell me what to do?

Answer (score 7):

Set your oven to 175, because it's in Celsius and the recipe is in Fahrenheit.